# Play Framework Anorm withConnection Error

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following case class and class in Play Framework 2.5. Since the DB object has been deprecated I'm trying to use the new dependency inject methodology but not understanding why my code does not compile. The old method works fine, the new method has compilation error.

missing parameter type on the implicit connection =>

[image]

```
package models

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import play.db._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import anorm._
import play.api.db.DB
import play.api.Play.current


case class Department(id: Int,
                      name: String)

@Singleton
class DepartmentDao @Inject() (dBApi: DBApi) {

  private val db = dBApi.getDatabase("default")

  val simple = {
    get[Int]("department.id") ~
      get[String]("department.name") map {
      case id ~ name => Department(id, name)
    }
  }

  def getDepartments = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL("SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT")
  }

  def getDepartmentsNew = db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL("SELECT * FROM DEPARMTMENT")
  }

}
```

UPDATE:

I've placed what the code looked like before was I was originally trying to get it working. Unless I am missing something this code should run. It is identical to code I've seen in multiple sample projects.

```
@Singleton
class DepartmentDao @Inject() (dBApi: DBApi) {

  private val db = dBApi.getDatabase("default")

  val simple = {
    get[Int]("department.id") ~
      get[String]("department.name") map {
      case id ~ name => Department(id, name)
    }
  }

  def getDepartments: Seq[Department] = db.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL("SELECT * FROM DEPARMTMENT").as(simple.*)
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you have inference issue. BTW it's better to indicate explicitly the expected return types for the public/non local `def`.

Comment: Try replacing dBApi.getDatabase("default") with dBApi.database("default")

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a database method, getDatabase is the only I see that makes sense

Comment: The updated code is not identical, not even sufficiently similar. As suggested, there was an inference issue, by calling the generic higher order function `withConnection[T](f:Connection=>T):T` without a sufficient context to infer `T` from there. That's also why it's recommend to explicitly add the return type to the functions which represent the feature of your API (to give proper type context).

Comment: One minor thing. Importing `play.db._` you are using Java apis. Hence you get `getDatabase` not `database`. Try `play.api.db._`